# Set default usestate with array of objects from props

Tags: reactjs, undefined, jsx, use-state

I have a weird situation. I have the following code which is not working.

```
const [result, setResult] = useState(props.fileNamesStatus.map((file, i) => {
    return {
        key: file.fileStatus
    }
}));
```

Strangely though, it works sometimes and sometimes it does not.  I have used it in the `JSX` as follows:

> I get the error `Cannot read property 'key' of undefined`

```
<ul className="in">
     {props.fileNamesStatus.map((file, i) => {
           console.log(result[i].key)     /// Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    
     })}
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you copy props to state and then use props in render? Why do you need state at all?

Comment: @AnastasiiaSolop I am building a toggle feature inside a map. The toggle works on click, I am setting up state to keep track of its state (enable/disable)

Comment: It is generally a pretty bad idea to copy props to state and keep them in sync. It always leads to complications and other bugs. You should avoid it whenever you can. But if you have to, make sure that you run useEffect and copy props to state whenever they change, I'll add an example in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.fileNamesStatus && props.fileNamesStatus.length) {
    setResult(props.fileNamesStatus.map((file, i) => {
      return {
        key: file.fileStatus
      }
    }))
  }
}, [props.fileNamesStatus])
```

But even with this change there is a chance that in your render props and state will be out of sync, so you should add additional check `console.log(result[i] ? result[i].key : 'out of sync')`

Comment: i console logged `props.fileNamesStatus` inside useEffect and it is empty. Although data does exist in it.

Comment: Is it a simple array of objects? How do you know that data is in it if console log shows it's empty?